# How to write controller in Spring boot to accept a query String from the format- /policies?page=2&limit=10

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I want to write a controller for the URL request:

```
    @GetMapping(value= "/policies", params = {"page,limit"})
public ResponseEntity<String>  getAllPolicies(@RequestParam int paginationValue,@RequestParam int limit, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers){
 }
```

What is the suitable approach to write the controller? As there seems to be issue in using the above method, while using the above code i fail to capture the page and limit value.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please precisely explain your problem.

Comment: Please provide more information such as relevant stack trace and/or how the error occurred. And what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may specify @RequestParam(name) for paginationValue :

```
@GetMapping(value= "/policies", params = {"page,limit"})
public ResponseEntity<String>  getAllPolicies(@RequestParam("page") int paginationValue,
@RequestParam int limit, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers){  }
```

Or alternatively, change parameter names, as below :

```
public ResponseEntity<String>  getAllPolicies(@RequestParam int page,@RequestParam int limit, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers){
 }
```